# How can I load objects in PFQueryTableViewController with parse version 1.12.0 in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, parse-server

Somebody know how can I get the objects from PFQueryTableViewController with the new SDK Parse Objective C version 1.12.0?
I got  this error on debug shell when objectsDidLoad and objectsWillLoad methods are executing:

> [Error]: improper usage of $dontSelect (Code: 102, Version: 1.12.0)

I'm running parse-server on my own dedicated server

**Edit**

Here is my code:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {


PFQuery *bann = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Banned"];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

[query whereKey:@"qUser" doesNotMatchKey:@"bannedUser" inQuery:bann];


if (self.objects.count == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}

return query;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't really help you when you don't post any code.
A quick search for Parse's error code 102 brings up the follow:

```
    /**
     * Error code indicating you tried to query with a datatype that doesn't
     * support it, like exact matching an array or object.
     * @constant
     */
    INVALID_QUERY: 102,
```